# Minify HTML and Magento 2 - Some Resources not minified

Tags: magento2, minify

I'm updating from 2.2.3 to 2.2.5 and just testing a few bits however have found in **page speed insights** that **Minify HTML** seems to be a slight issue even though it's turned on within `Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Template Settings -> Minify HTML`.

The following resources show as not being minified:

```
Minifying .../template/authentication-popup.html could save 309B (29% reduction) after compression.
Minifying ..._Checkout/template/minicart/content.html could save 215B (20% reduction) after compression.
Minifying …ento_Ui/templates/modal/modal-slide.html could save 169B (27% reduction) after compression.
Minifying o_Captcha/template/checkout/captcha.html could save 167B (27% reduction) after compression.
Minifying …nto_Ui/templates/modal/modal-custom.html could save 145B (24% reduction) after compression.
Minifying …ento_Ui/templates/modal/modal-popup.html could save 144B (24% reduction) after compression.
Minifying …/en_GB/Magento_Ui/template/messages.html could save 137B (43% reduction) after compression.
Minifying buzzluma/en_GB/mage/gallery/gallery.html could save 135B (24% reduction) after compression.
Minifying …tPurchase/template/instant-purchase.html could save 111B (28% reduction) after compression.
Minifying …agento_Ui/templates/tooltip/tooltip.html could save 102B (37% reduction) after compression.
```

I know its only a tiny improvement but it's annoying me as to why these are not minified and am wondering if anyone know how to fix or has happened to anyone else?

This does not happen on the live store on 2.2.3 and that optimisation shows as already present.

Comment: Hi, have you found any solution for it ?

Comment: No nothing yet have left it for now as was minimal bytes just in my backlog if i get time.